# Element to search in binary tree in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm very new to Prolog, and trying to find an element to search in binary tree, it finds it successfully but the problem is if it doesn't it still gives yes, I want it to say no or to say not found. My code is:

```
child(1,2,3).
child(2,4,5).
child(3,6,7).
node(1,a).
node(2,b).
node(3,c).
node(4,d).
node(5,f).
node(6,f).
node(7,g).


show(X):-
    write('element is found in node: '),write(X),nl.
inc(X,Y,Z):-
    Y is X+X,
    Z is X+X+1.


find(A):-
    traverse3(1,A).
traverse3(X,A):-
    check(X,A),
    inc(X,Y,Z),
    child(X,Y,Z),
    traverse3(Y,A),
    traverse3(Z,A).

check(X,A):- not(node(X,A)).

check(X,A):- 
    node(X,A),
    show(X).
traverse3(X,A):- not(child(X,Y,Z)).
```

Comment: You want `find` to print out all of the occurrences it finds (as opposed to stopping at each one), and then remember whether or not it found any when it is done?

Comment: One issue is that `check(X,A) :- not(node(X,A))` says that the check for a node is successful even if the node doesn't exist. I see that you have this in order to get your `traverse3/2` to work the way you designed it, but I think `traverse3/2` needs rework to avoid having to do this.

Comment: you may consider more common tree approach `tree(?leftBranch, ?elem, ?rightBranch)`

Answer (score 1):

This is an unusual binary tree. But anyway, since you have already "normalized" it to a database representation, all you have to do to find an element is to ask for it.

In other words, if your program `tree.pl` consists only of the `child/3` and `node/2` facts:

```
child(1,2,3).
child(2,4,5).
child(3,6,7).
node(1,a).
node(2,b).
node(3,c).
node(4,d).
node(5,f).
node(6,f).
node(7,g).
```

You can simply query for the element you need:

```
?- [tree].
true.

?- node(N, a).
N = 1.

?- node(N, f).
N = 5 ;
N = 6.

?- node(4, E).
E = d.

?- node(N, E).
N = 1, E = a ;
N = 2, E = b ;
N = 3, E = c ;
N = 4, E = d ;
N = 5, E = f ;
N = 6, E = f ;
N = 7, E = g.
```

Or is there something I am missing?